# Is this still a Ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

We know $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v})^TA(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v})\le1$ is a general ellipsoid.

I am doing a statistical calculation.

I wonder if  $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v})^TA(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v})\le d$ is still a ellipsoid?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain (x-v)

Comment: @Narasimham That is just translating the origin from $0$ to $v$. The $d$ influences the extension. First form looks like hull and interior, second form might give single point if $d = 0$ or outside if  $d < 0$, assuming $A$ is positive definitite.

Comment: Tag convex analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace $A$ in the first inequality by $d^{-1}A$, you get the second inequality. So yes, **except** your initial statement is incorrect: It is only true if $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks, I see, A  should be positive definite.